# Running a Motor Driver Board L298N on 12v power supply with the BBC Micro:bit

Tags: motordriver, bbc-microbit

sorry if my query sounds odd. I am trying to determine whether my micro:bit will be affected badly if I did the following:

I have the GND wire of it's battery pack and the GND wire of the 9v battery running through the POWER GND pin of the driver. Currently, the 5V pin of the driver is being used, not the 12V power. I have coded a  2 wheeled( dc gear motor) buggy and want to 'upgrade' it to a 4 wheeled 'monster' buggy.

If I were to use the 12V pin ( and provide the 12V for the power supply, would the GND affect the micro:bit badly at all?

Thanks for your help, I'm new to this and this is my first question too. Any help about electronics is appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about hardware.

Comment: Maybe you can try your luck at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Many thanks! will do so, thank you for the link :)

Comment: That's fine Filburt It can be closed. Ruud Helderman was kind enough to point me in the right direction. T

Comment: Thanks again Ruud, I found more answers there!